Unable to receive access token after Microsoft login - "AX Lookup problem" error
I am working on integrating Microsoft Authentication into my app. After successfully logging in to a Microsoft account, I am unable to receive the access token. Instead, I encounter the following error:

AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:838

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Could you provide guidance on how to resolve it?
Package used : flutter_appauth 8.0.3
Link : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth
Thanks in advance!

By using webview_flutter, you can handle the Microsoft authentication flow within a WebView, which may help avoid the issues you're facing with flutter_appauth.
